# How to set up the map for my playing style?

Tags: civilization-6

I like to start on a large island of my own and not make contact until I am some way up the tech tree, preferably with an advantage.

In previous CIVs, I would generate the map, take a peek and discard until I found a good one.

I have done this 30+ times and there is always either an AI player on the same landmass, or is is too small. This despite only having 4 opponents on a huge map.

Does anyone else have similar playing style? How do  yo choose your start options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Modding Option**

If modding is your thing this could be a solution for you. There's a setting in the GlobalParameters.xml called START_DISTANCE_MAJOR_CIVILIZATION which is default set to 9. Meaning that civilizations cannot be closer than 9 tiles away from each other at the start of the game (maybe 8, I'm not sure if it's an inclusive/exclusive 9).

**Existing Mod**

There is a mod ([here](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=899688103&searchtext=Start%20distance)) that boosts the start distance between starting civilizations from 9 to 16.

*Note that I am not the creator of this mod nor do I know the owner, I simply searched for it on the steam workshop.*

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, there are not a ton of options for landmasses in Civilization 6. If you really want a decently large landmass to yourself, try using the Island Plates map setting. It normally results in medium sized islands. Keep the opponents down as you were doing, six seems to be a good number, but four should all but guarantee it.

Comment: It always seems to generate 2 or three humongous continents. I have been hoping to get a large island of my own, of the coast, but, so far, have always been on the same land mass at as least one other race, even with only 4 opponents :-(   The best that I can mange is to find a choke-hold place for a city and to seize the larger part of the land-mass and really defend that city well